# How to prevent multiple select in radio button?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I've this code:

```
<form name="quiz" ng-submit="quiz.answer(selected)">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="selected" ng-value="true"> Red
  </label>
  <br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="selected" ng-value="false"> Green
  </label>
  <br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="selected" ng-value="false"> Blue
  </label>
  <br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="selected" ng-value="false"> Yellow
  </label>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

How do I prevent ALL of the false values from being selected at once if I click one?

Comment: Well, the question is: why do you have 3 radio buttons with the same value?

Comment: Also I suggest you to read the **docs** https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D on how and when to use `ng-value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding you want to group the radio buttons such that one is selected at a time you can do it by adding name attribute in each radio button and give same name to all of them. So at time of submit you can get the value of selected variable in submit function call.

```
   <form name="quiz" ng-submit="quiz.answer(selected)">
         <label>
    <input type="radio" name="quizOption" ng-model="selected" ng-value="true">
    Red
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="quizOption" ng-model="selected" ng-value="false">
    Green
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="quizOption" ng-model="selected" ng-value="false">
    Blue
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="quizOption" ng-model="selected" ng-value="false">
    Yellow
  </label><br/>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<form name="quiz" ng-submit="quiz.answer(selected)">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="selected" ng-value="red">
    Red
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="selected" ng-value="green">
    Green
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="selected" ng-value="blue">
    Blue
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="selected" ng-value="yellow">
    Yellow
  </label><br/>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Give each of the radio buttons a distinct value.

Comment: Also `ng-value` is really unnecessary in this case.

Comment: having the same value does not work, but have all the attribute have the same name. This is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/darkkyoun/ve9nohmp/10/